# remove extra space in slick slider

Tags: jquery, css, slider, slick.js

In slick slider I want to use **center mode** with **infinite** *false* but the first slide should start from left **edge** and last slide should end in right **edge**.

I just want to remove the **extra spacing** as shown in images below.

[First slide left side space](https://i.stack.imgur.com/u0zHX.jpg)

[Last slide right side space](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fK1Z5.jpg)

Comment: give your code or link of your project.

Comment: i am creating jsfiddle link w8 for it

Comment: @SagarKodte Here is [Jsfiddle link](https://jsfiddle.net/jpq1s386/) please use it

Comment: how you want to show front image? full image or now showing that like having margin on both side?

Comment: same as now but the first slide must start from edge without any space and same for last slide

Comment: it's not possible if i move first one to the left edge so there is gap appear oin first and second

Comment: you have to show full width image in center with showing one image only on front

Comment: you do it however you see it possible and show me

Comment: check this https://jsfiddle.net/jpq1s386/1/

Comment: oh thats what you meant but i want to show the clip of other slide too like in my previous JsFiddle

Comment: actually I want to make a carousel slider like that in facebook ads [Facebook Carousel link ads](https://www.facebook.com/business/a/online-sales/carousel-link-ads)